# Powershell and command line are only running in legacy mode under Windows 10

Tags: powershell, windows-10

How can I solve it? Have no clue why that happens.

- Given result
  If I uncheck legacy mode the consoles stopped running: after opening the window freezes and nothing more happens (affect either PowerShell and command line):

[image: freezed window]

- Expected result
  PowerShell and command line can be used in regular mode and are not rely to run in legacy mode.

Comment: from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/legacymode:  >If you experience an issue that requires you to use the legacy console that is not documented here, please contact the team on the [microsoft/terminal](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/) GitHub repository or via the [Feedback Hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-insider/feedback-hub/feedback-hub-app) for assistance."

Answer (score 1):

If it runs in legacy mode but both Powershell and CMD freeze then there's probably something wrong with your windows install.

There's a variety of ways and programs you can use to try and troubleshoot (like [Microsoft Sysinternals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sysinternals-suite)) but that's beyond the scope of what Stack Overflow is for

Here's a couple Stack Exchange sites you can ask for help troubleshooting the OS:

- [Super User](https://superuser.com/) for end user machines
- [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) for network admins and servers